# Access rest api using nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, rest

I am trying to access opencorporates.com and using their REST API.
I got this code from [How to make remote REST call inside Node.js? any CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643321/how-to-make-remote-rest-call-inside-node-js-any-curl). But it is not fetching any data. I tried wget on the url and it worked perfectly fine.

app.js

```
var https = require('http');

var optionsget = {
host : 'opencorporates.com', 

port : 8080,
path : '/v0.2/companies/search?q=barclays+bank&jurisdiction_code=gb', 
method : 'GET' 
};


console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

var reqGET = https.get(optionsget, function(res) {
console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.info('GET result:\n');
    process.stdout.write(d);
    console.info('\n\nCall completed');
  });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Node runs asynchronously, the returned data is broken into chunks.

The `.on('data')` event returns a portion of the data, which you then need to stitch/append back to a variable. You can then capture the complete output with `.on('end')`.

See this example for more info: [Why is node.js breaking incoming data into chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237015/why-is-node-js-breaking-incoming-data-into-chunks) (@vossad01's answer)

That said, @SilviuBurcea's suggestion to use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) is a much simpler way of handling http requests so you don't have to write and handle all of this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Try using request module. https://github.com/mikeal/request It's the http module on steroids.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. 
But what exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: It's very low level, you don't have the onEnd handler and you have a few typos. Request is much powerful and leverages these low level calls.

Comment: Speaking of steroids, have you heard of https://github.com/simov/purest It's built on top of _request_ and it's designed especially for REST APIs

Answer (score 1):

Tried running the code locally, and first there is a capitalization error

```
var reqGET = https.get(optionsget, function(res) {

reqGet.end();
```

Second, the web address was not working at the address, nor with secure

```
var optionsget = {
host : 'api.opencorporates.com', 
port : 80,
path : '/v0.2/companies/search?q=barclays+bank&jurisdiction_code=gb', 
method : 'GET' 
};
```

Its worth noting that if you wanted to actually use https, you would need to change the require line

```
var https = require('https');
```

Comment: I rectified the capitalization error. 
The web address is working in my browser, it displays a json formatted data. http://api.opencorporates.com/v0.2/companies/search?q=barclays+bank&jurisdiction_code=gb
Still the code doesn't return any data.

Answer (score 0):

This is fully functional version for your reference:

```
var http = require('http');

var optionsget = {
    host : 'api.opencorporates.com',
    port : 80,
    path : '/v0.2/companies/search?q=barclays+bank&jurisdiction_code=gb',
    method : 'GET'
};


console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

var reqGet = http.get(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    buffer='';

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        //console.info('GET result:\n');
        //process.stdout.write(d);
        buffer += d.toString();
        //console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        console.log(buffer);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});

reqGet.end();
```